# Add image to option in select with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working with firebase ! so decided to put the retrieving the data in a datalist element and add the image next to the option value like this :

[image]

i managed to put the retrieved data in datalist option ! the problem is with the image i've tried to set `option.value="<img src=.....>`" but didn't work , also i ve tried to set `option.style='background-img:url()'` also didn't work

this is my code :

```
 var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('titres/');
        databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        const list = document.getElementById('select');
        [childKey].forEach(item => {
          let x = document.createElement("IMG");
          x.src=childData.URL_logo;
          let option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = item;   
          option.text= x;
          option.style="";
          list.appendChild(option);
        });
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `option.appendChild(x);`

Comment: it didn't work :/